# How do I save thousands of objects to Parse.com?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

In my iOS app that uses Parse, some users will need to save thousand of objects in one action. I've tried iterating through the array of data and creating/saving the objects one by one, but this results in the objects saving to my data browser pretty slowly. Each object only needs to contain a few strings, so I don't understand why its taking so long to save these objects.

Is there a faster way to save thousands of objects to Parse?

Comment: I'm just going to point out that it is likely that there is a MUCH better way of accomplishing what you want. If its just strings, why not upload the entire array as on object? Use JSON? Do they have to be individual objects?

Comment: I suppose they don't have to be, but I don't know how else to have these strings be associated with each other without creating objects.

Comment: If you're willing to go into a bit more detail of what you are trying to do maybe we can help you figure it out! Another thing you might want to consider is Parse.com charges you by reqs/second. So it might be worth restructuring your code to lower them.

Comment: Funny you mention that because that's another problem I was hoping to avoid. I'll create a similar situation: There's 2 kinds of users--group owners and participants. An owner creates a group and participants join the group. When the owner creates a group, an object representation of every song in the owner's device's library should be saved to Parse. Afterwards, those song objects' data should populate a table view (1 song/cell) which all group participants can see..

Comment: I see, that makes sense. In your case, I would simply upload the entire NSArray of songs as a new object and keep track of the user who owns it. This will allow you to update their songlist easier and be able to handle multiple groups quite well. When querying for all the songs you can simply query for all the songlists of each user for the group and merge it locally. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that does. I tried using JSON like you mentioned in your first comment to implement that, but turns out the JSON string becomes so lengthy that the object that owns that JSON string goes over the 128kb size limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edited:

I've always used [PFObject saveAllInBackground:array block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {}]; but....another method I have just attempted semi-successfully, was to upload a Json string as a PFFile(no 128k limit), and then use cloud code to parse it and create the necessary PFObjects. I was able to get this to work with small quantities, but unfortunately the cloud code timed out when using a large quantity. I instead opted to utilize a background job to perform the parsing. This takes a considerable amount of time before the data is completely available, but can handle the large amount of data. The upload time itself was much quicker. When using 1000 objects with 3 strings each upload was roughly .8 seconds, vs 23 seconds doing a save all in background, 5000 objects 3 strings each was only 2.5 seconds upload time. In addition to the quicker time you also get progress updates. Depending on the use-case, utilizing this alternative may work best if immediate and quick upload is important, vs making the data immediately available.

IOS Code:

```
  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        //subclass of PFObject
        Employee *employee = [Employee object];
        employee.firstName = @"FName";
        employee.lastName = @"LName";
        employee.employeeID = @"fid54";
        [array addObject:[employee dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:employee.allKeys]];
    }
    //Seperate class only to store the PFFiles
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"fileTestSave"];
    testObject[@"testFile"] = [PFFile fileWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:array options:0 error:nil]];

    NSLog(@"started");
    //**notice I am only saving the test object with the NSData from the JSONString**
    [testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error && succeeded) NSLog(@"succeeded");
        else NSLog(@"error");
    }];
```

Edited: Instead of saving in the beforeSave or afterSave Cloud Code which can cause timeout issues, the background job below can be run anytime. It grab all rows in the "fileTestSave" table, parses the JSON strings in those rows, and adds them to the "Person" table. Once completed it will rows from the table. All asynchronously!

```
var _ = require('underscore.js');
Parse.Cloud.job("userMigration", function(request, status) 
{

    // Set up to modify user data
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    //Table called fileTestSave stores a PFFile called "testFile" which we will use an HTTPRequest to get the data. Is there a better way to get the data?
    //This PFFile stores a json string which contains relavent data to add to the "Person" table
    var testFileSave = Parse.Object.extend("fileTestSave");
    var query = new Parse.Query(testFileSave);
    query.find().then(function(results) 
    {
        //Generate an array of promises
        var promises = [];

        _.each(results, function(testFileSaveInstance){
            //add promise to array
            promises.push(saveJsonPerson(testFileSaveInstance));
        });
        //only continue when all promises are complete
        return Parse.Promise.when(promises);
    }).then(function() 
    {

    // Set the job's success status
        console.log("Migration Completed NOW");
        status.success("Migration completed");
    }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
        status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
    });
});

function saveJsonPerson(fileTestSave)
{
    //Get the pffile testfile
    var testFile = fileTestSave.get("testFile");
    //get the fileURL from the PFFile to generate the http request
    var fileURL = testFile["url"]();
    //return the promise from the httpRequest
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        method:"GET",
        url: fileURL
    }).then(function(httpResponse){
            //return the promise from the parsing
            return parsehttpResponse(httpResponse,fileTestSave);
        },
        function(error){
            console.log("http response error");
        }
    );
}

function parsehttpResponse(httpResponse,fileTestSave)
{   
    var jsonArray = eval( '(' + httpResponse.text + ')' );
    var saveArray =[];

    //parse each person in the json string, and add them to the saveArray for bulk saving later.
    for (i in jsonArray) 
    {
        var personExtend = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
        var person = new personExtend();
        person.set("classDiscriminator",jsonArray[i]["classDiscriminator"]);
        person.set("lastName",jsonArray[i]["lastName"]);
        person.set("firstName",jsonArray[i]["firstName"]);
        person.set("employeeID",jsonArray[i]["employeeID"]);
        saveArray.push(person);
    };
    //return the promise from the saveAll(bulk save)
    return Parse.Object.saveAll(
            saveArray
        ).then(function(){
                //return the promise from the destory
                return fileTestSave.destroy(

                    ).then(function(){

                    },function(error){
                            console.log("error destroying");
                        }
                );
        },function(error){
                console.log("Error Saving");
            }
    );
}
```

Old Cloud Code that timed out as reference:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("fileTestSave", function(request) {

    //When accessing PFFiles you don't get the actual data, there may be an easier way, but I just utitlized an HTTPRequest to get the data, and then continued parsing.
    var file = request.object.get("testFile");
    var fileURL = file["url"]();
    console.log("URL:"+fileURL);
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method:"GET",
            url: fileURL,
            success: function(httpResponse) 
            {
                var jsonArray = eval( '(' + httpResponse.text + ')' );
                var saveArray =[];
                for (i in jsonArray) 
                {
                    var personExtend = Parse.Object.extend("Person");
                    var person = new personExtend();
                                    //May be a better way to parse JSON by using each key automatically, but I'm still new to JS, and Parse so I set each individually.
                    person.set("classDiscriminator",array[i]["classDiscriminator"]);
                    person.set("lastName",array[i]["lastName"]);
                    person.set("firstName",array[i]["firstName"]);
                    person.set("employeeID",array[i]["employeeID"]);
                    saveArray.push(person);
                };
                Parse.Object.saveAll(saveArray,
                {
                    success: function(list) {
                      // All the objects were saved.
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                      // An error occurred while saving one of the objects.
                    },
                });
            },
            error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log("http response error");
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: How small of quantities were you able to get this to work with?

Comment: The quantity seems to vary, I think i tried 60 yesterday and 50 succeeded, I just did 100 several times with success, then tried 200 and 105 made it. Not reliable and in these cases saveinbackground works just as quickly so no real savings. I think the best, and maybe only, use-case would be to save a large amount of objects, and the parse it using a background job.

Did you try or were you having problems with saveAllInBackground? Albeit slower it worked and saved all 1000 objects in 23 seconds.

Comment: I added the background job code that does not time out. It queries all rows on the table, gets the JSON string, parses them into "Person"s then than saves them to the table asynchronously. This does not time out, and I just tested it with 6k items. It takes some time but it does work! I uploaded 15k objects again 3 sting each(only 1.4mb file) and it took 11 seconds, I attempted only 1500 items and saveAllInbackground failed at 1200 object with a timeout error. So all in all this method can allow you to upload a LOT more data than conventional upload, but again not immediately available.

Comment: Yeah, of roughly 1200 objects saveAllinBackground would time out at around 750 objects consistently. I will try this out and report back!

Comment: Why don't you use the Cloud Code Function instead of Job? Cloud Code Function has 13 seconds timeout in compare with after/beforeSave that have only 3 seconds. 13 seconds would be more than enough to parse and save thousands of objects.

Comment: Oh, I see, Parse has limitations on request size, so you can't send too much data to your Cloud Code Function at once: `request size exceeds limits. Max allowed 1048576 current request is 2045991`

Comment: You could upload to a table and execute the cloud code upon completion instead of the background job if the file size is small enough.

Answer (score 2):

Another method for uploading thousands of objects in the background, again this takes some time but can be sized to avoid timing out, as arrays are saved in chunks recursively. I've had no problem saving 10k+ items. Implemented as a category, just enter how many objects at a time you want save at a time, it will save them in the background serially, and recursively until all objects are saved, it also features progress updating via a separate block.

```
//  PFObject+addOns.h
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface PFObject (addOns)
+(void)saveAllInBackground:(NSArray *)array chunkSize:(int)chunkSize block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block progressBlock:(PFProgressBlock)progressBlock;
@end


#import "PFObject+addOns.h"

@interface PFObject (addOns_internal)
+(void)saveAllInBackground:(NSArray *)array chunkSize:(int)chunkSize block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block trigger:(void(^)())trigger;
@end

@implementation PFObject (addOns)

+(void)saveAllInBackground:(NSArray *)array chunkSize:(int)chunkSize block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block progressBlock:(PFProgressBlock)progressBlock
{
    unsigned long numberOfCyclesRequired = array.count/chunkSize;
    __block unsigned long count = 0;
    [PFObject saveAllInBackground:array chunkSize:chunkSize block:block trigger:^() {
        count++;
        progressBlock((int)(100.0*count/numberOfCyclesRequired));
    }];
}

+(void)saveAllInBackground:(NSArray *)array chunkSize:(int)chunkSize block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block trigger:(void(^)())trigger
{

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, array.count <= chunkSize ? array.count:chunkSize);
    NSArray *saveArray = [array subarrayWithRange:range];
    NSArray *nextArray = nil;
    if (range.length<array.count) nextArray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(range.length, array.count-range.length)];
    [PFObject saveAllInBackground:saveArray block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if(!error && succeeded && nextArray){
            trigger(true);
            [PFObject saveAllInBackground:nextArray chunkSize:chunkSize block:block trigger:trigger];
        }
        else
        {
            trigger(true);
            block(succeeded,error);
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

Comment: Edited, added a completion block, and made it a category to PFObject.

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you @hybrdthry911 . Would it make any sense to add a delay between calls to the saveAllInBackground:chunkSize:block:trigger function? If I'm thinking about it correctly, adding a 1 sec delay between recursions may help to space api calls out further, reducing the per/sec count. Of course this would take longer to complete the overall save (maybe add `beginBackgroundTask / endBackgroundTask` block to ensure completion if app is closed), but it could prevent hitting the call limit if you have multiple users transferring large #s of rows.

Comment: what maximum chunk size is supported by Parse?

Comment: It's not about the size but more so about timing out. It would depend on the size of the object you are saving.

Comment: @hybrdthry911 is there a reliable way to calculate appropriate chunk size according to records size?

Comment: or there is nothing to do but to rely on guesswork

Comment: Hmm. your solution doesn't work for me, while uploading 5000 records. Parse returns an error: `This application performed 1818 requests within the past minute, and exceeded its request limit. Please retry in one minute or raise your request limit`

Comment: Try larger chunk sizes or my other implementation using a JSon pffile

Comment: Regardless of chunk size, Parse prevent all operations after I create first 1.75K records. So I'm really doubt your PFFile solution would work. Maybe they improved limits system and this cheats won't work anymore?

Comment: I've implemented cloud code function which also accept chunks and create new records on server side. It also fails after 1.75K records created.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this with sending the save process in quantities of five into the background, so to speak fork it, "thread" it, as apple would refer to it.

here is the link to apples ios threading guides.
I have not used it yet, but I will soon need it as well, as I'm working on a massive database app.

here's the link

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/AboutThreads/AboutThreads.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of objects, you can use `saveAllInBackgroundWithBlock`. This method takes an array of PFObjects as its argument:

[https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:block](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground%3ablock):

Comment: Wasn't me ;P This is certainly the simplest solution, but for my case, times out before all of my objects finish saving.

Answer (score 0):

For the faster processing, you can use the parse cloud code, whihc is simply a javascript. You can create a function which takes the array of the data as argument and then in function, you can save the objects.
Parse cloud code has better processing speed than the native one.

For its use, you can refer :

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide
https://parse.com/docs/js_guide