# PARSE - how to save a large table with 800 records to Parse class in one-go, instead of using For-Loop to save each array of one record at one time

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform

If I have a table with 800 student records.

Each student record has several fields , e.g student ID, student name, contact no.

How can I save all these records in one-go, than using a For-loop to loop each record in an array one by one.

As it takes quite long time to save all 800 records if I did so.

Kindly please share your advices and experience how I can shorten the time required.

Comment: is each record a Parse Object (e.g. PFObject)?

Comment: may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841017/how-do-i-save-thousands-of-objects-to-parse-com

Comment: PFObject has a static method to saveAll.  800 ought to be fine., but when quantities are large enough, this can fail due to timeout.  The next step then, is to saveAll in smaller batches, waiting for each batch to complete.  This is kind of a syntactic pain in iOS with completion blocks as your only tool.  For the very large case, its better to move the work to cloud code and use parse's JS promise implementation.